# Haskel type error

Tags: haskell, types

Hello I am new to Haskel, and I am trying to write some code for a project I have, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR file:.\Lab1.hs:12 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : c c
*** Term           : c
*** Type           : Int
*** Does not match : a -> b
```

---

My code looks like this. What am I doing wrong?

```
grade :: Int->Int->Int                           
grade a b 
    |((a < 0) || (a > 100) || (b < 0) || (b > 0)) = -1
    |(c > 47) && (a <= 47) = 47
    |(c > 47) && (a > 47) && (c <50) = 50
    |otherwise = c
    c where
    c = ((8 * a) `div` 10) + b
```

Comment: This is a typo: you put an extra `c` before the `where`, which makes the value in your `otherwise` clause `c c`, rather than `c`.

Comment: @duplode Oh I see! Thank you!

Comment: If you are using `-1` simply as a marker to indicate invalid inputs, then you should consider changing your type to `Int -> Int -> Maybe Int` and returning `Nothing` in the first case (and `Just 47`, `Just 50`, `Just c` in the others).

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code using ghci and once i removed the c right before the where it worked fine.

```
grade :: Int->Int->Int                           
grade a b 
 |((a < 0) || (a > 100) || (b < 0) || (b > 0)) = -1
 |(c > 47) && (a <= 47) = 47
 |(c > 47) && (a > 47) && (c <50) = 50
 |otherwise = c
 where
 c = ((8 * a) `div` 10) + b
```

Also if you intend to only go into the first case if b is not zero i would suggest to write the first condition like this

```
|((a < 0) || (a > 100) || (not (b==0))) = -1
```